# System mapping solution for SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, diagramming

Looking for an IT data mapping solution that integrates with SharePoint 2013.

Need to be able to capture information about IT systems, how they relate, how the data flows through each system. Must be able to dynamically generate diagrams on the fly.

Comment: Integrates is what way? You want the data stored in SharePoint lists? You want the diagrams published to SharePoint? A little more info on what you want to do would go a long way. Are you sure you wouldn't be better off with a dedicated tool such as an Enterprise Architecture tool?

Comment: SharePoint list would be ideal. The end goal is to be able to store system information details on our company's SharePoint, then allow non-IT department users to be able to see what systems/departments holds specific types of information and see how the systems interact. For example, I want to see all system that hold HR related information and see how the HR systems interact with other systems. Ideally you could click on an icon and then drill down to more information like point of contact information for the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there is nothing like this that Integrates to SharePoint. You would have to create something bespoke.

Indeed, I would not recommend that approach as I think that the level of complexity and size of data is likely to quickly outstrip anything that would be especially performant in SP. SP is already a complex set of data and adding further complexity is not wise in my experience.

SP lists are good for simple data. I've been starting to create a service catalogue for ourselves in SP but it will be a very simple list & even as I've been thinking about it,  I've quickly realised that it might not be suitable for long. Also, I'm not planning to hold much in the way of data interfaces.

Instead, I would recommend a solution that is more focussed with a database and a web front end that could easily be integrated to the SP site or simply linked.

These kind of systems tend to get very complex as you begin to discover links between systems and unless your organisation is relatively small and simple, I think you will regret it.

If your system architecture is at all complex, you would be better off with a fully-fledged Enterprise Architecture tool. That would allow you to begin to correctly map the logic between systems and even to map systems to infrastructure.

In short, to use SP, keep it very simple (simplistic) and forget the diagrams for now as you would have to create a bespoke interface anyway. Consider a bespoke database with web front end that can be linked to your AD for authentication and authorisation the same as SP and simply linked to from SP. Or for a more complex architecture, investigate the use of an Enterprise Architecture tool.

UPDATE:

OK, so you need something simple to draw out the data. That is a bit easier. I'm still not aware of a dedicated web part but to be honest, I've not looked.

My approach would probably be to use a JavaScript "[Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28data_structure%29)" tool - note the phrase "graph" not to be confused with "chart". A chart is a pictorial view of (often numeric) data. A graph is a set of nodes and "edges" (I probably haven't explained that very well). Graphviz is the most famous of such tools but that is a command line tool. However, there are plenty of JavaScript tools that might be used.

SharePoint is delightfully easy to integrate with JavaScript (apart from the bizarre field names and hopelessly overcomplex data structures!) & even with my limited skills, I was able to knock up a Google map "view" that uses the data from a normal SharePoint list. With a bit of help from a JavaScript library of course.

You simply hide the normal View Web Part. The data is available to the web page still and you can feed it straight into a JavaScript library that will do the graphing for you.

Here are some free and none-free libraries in case you chose to go this route:

Free:

- [SigmaJS](http://sigmajs.org/)
- [VisJS](http://visjs.org/)
- [Arbor](http://arborjs.org/)
- [Springy](http://getspringy.com/)

Not Free

- [GoJs](http://www.gojs.net/latest/index.html) - Not used it but this looks fab. Interactive Diagrams for the
  Web - unlimited trial but watermarked, USD thousands
- [jGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html) USD 10's thousands
- [ZoomCharts](https://zoomcharts.com/en/gallery/) - USD hundreds

Worth also noting that, in theory, you could do this with Visio. However, there are not many examples out there because it is so complex.

Comment: Your response is well noted; however, the purpose of the tool is not for Enterprise Architecture purposes (which I would agree a fully-fledged Enterprise Architecture tool would be what is needed). What I'm looking for is a solution where I can take structured data (maybe from a SP list, or maybe from a database) and create a simple diagram/flowchart to show how information flows through a system. The audience is management and operations folks, not IT. Creating the list/database is the easy part. All I need is some kind of web part that can graph/map based on the SP list/database.

Comment: "All"! Maybe not so simple, things rarely are with SharePoint but hopefully my update might point you in a fairly easy direction. I'd love to hear how it turns out. If you do go this way, please blog about it and add an comment to this answer for people to refer to.

Comment: @random21 Interested to see how the integration would be done. If you shared us the details we'll sort you out a free mxGraph license (linked in answer).